# Got wrong size of dimensions after using "dataloader"

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor, pytorch-dataloader

Encountering a problem when trying to use "dataloader" to segment my dataset .

I used gray picture which displays pixel as ( 2294 * 1914). First, using "transforms",

then got tensor.size( ) = ( 1, 2294, 1914) .

But after using "dataloader", the returning .size( )
got ( 8, 1, 2294, 1914, 3) ,

which should be ( 8, 1, 2294, 1914) .

The last dimension "3 " copied every pixel three-times, and i have no idea where the problem is .

Any help will be appreciated !

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision
import torch.utils.data
from PIL import Image


training_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Lambda(lambda image: torch.from_numpy(np.array(image)   \
    .astype(np.float32)).unsqueeze(0)),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda image: image / 65535)
])


training_dataset_path = r"D:\user\Desktop\bcResearch\root"
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root =                \
training_dataset_path, transform = training_transforms)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader                             \
(dataset = train_dataset, batch_size = 8, shuffle = False)


img = Image.open                                                       \
(r"D:\user\Desktop\bcResearch\root\2\Subroot1_Sub1_subroot3_IM1.tiff")
img = training_transforms(img)
print(img.size())


for i, j in train_loader:
    print(i.size())
    print(i)
    break

#end
```

[Result is in the link here. (I have insufficient permissions to paste the picture directly. )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiT63.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my old friend, i already found the answer to problem caused by not adding `transforms.Grayscale()` in the `transform.Compose([])`.

Answer (score 0):

The question requires a bit of edit:
It shows return size `( 8, 1, 2294, 1914, 3)` instead of `( 5, 1, 2294, 1914, 3)` where `batch_size=8`.

Regarding the question,

> The last dimension "3 " copied every pixel three-times, and i have no
> idea where the problem is .

`torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` returns `(sample, target)` where `target` is the class_index of the target class.

So, according to the returned size, `3` is for the number of `target classes` and `sample size = (8, 1, 2294, 1914)`.

See [reference](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder).

Comment: Hi, kkgarg. Thank for your answer. I will edit my question as soon. And i need time to think about your answer, because when using RGB colorful picture, the return size of dimensions are the value which i wonder. However, your answer gives me a little inspiration.